# Why is (long) always rounding the number down?

Tags: c++, c++11

Yesterday I faced a problem that I could not explain. I was writing a very simple function that converts a double number to long. It was a part of another program. I used the following code:

```
long converter(double x) {
return (long) x; 
}
```

It worked perfectly until I entered `1.9` as the input and the result was `1`. But `1.9` is closer to `2` than it is to `1`. So, the result should be `2` rather than `1`.

Why is this problem happening? Can you give me a solution that solves this irritating problem?

Comment: Because simple casting behaves like that. You can use [`std::lround()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) in stead.

Comment: You should round them off along with typecasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting to long does not round a number correctly. To do that, you have to use `std::lround()`. Just use the following code:

```
long converter(double x) {
return std::lround(x); 
}
```

This should get the job done. Also, remember to include `<cmath>` in your code. Otherwise, it might not work.

P.S. std::lround() may not be compatible with older compilers. So, remember to use the latest version of your compiler.

Comment: Minor nitpick: to use `std::lround`, you should include `<cmath>`, and use the correct qualification (`std::`). Including `<math.h>` gives you `lround` (in global namespace).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Casting it to `long` won't round it as you expect. It will just discard the fractional part and will give you integer part . Therefore , you get `1` not `2`.

You can refer [`std::lround`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) here .

Answer (score 2):

You can use like

```
long converter(double x){
if(x>0)
    return (long)(x+0.5);
else
    return (long)(x-0.5);
}
```

As casting discard fractional part you can not get what you expect. Adding '0.5'  take the number to next long if fraction greater than '0.5'.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting from an floating point type to integral type will (if it will fit) do so by just discarding the fractional part. That is `1.9` converts to `1` and `-1.9` converts to `-1`.

The reason this was done is due to the way floating point values are stored (if there were an ambiguity here they would probably have chosen this conversion to be implementation defined to some degree). The number is contains of three parts: the sign, the mantissa and the exponent. These are binary, but the decimal equivalent would be `+1.9e+0` where `+` is the sign, `1.9` is the mantissa and `+0` is the exponent. The conversion of the mantissa+exponent to an integer becomes quite easy and fast if you just take the mantissa and shifts it to be an integer. After that you apply the sign. So the operation becomes to mask out the mantissa, and exponent and then doing a shift and last negate if the sign bit is set.

Had they chosen to actually do a proper rounding one would just have to do a little more job. The standard settled for the somewhat easier solution for defining the cast.